# MySQL Read/Write Benchmark

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, benchmark

I'm trying to benchmark Read/Write speed in MySQL 5.5. Currently I have a stored procedure that insert rows with random numbers to a table and I'm measuring time of execution before and after configuration changes.

Here's my procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertRand`(IN nor INT, in minr int, in maxr int)
begin
        declare i int;
        declare lastid int;
        set i =1;
        start transaction;
        while i <= nor do
        insert into tbltest(Value) values (minr + CEIL(rand() * (maxr-minr)));
        set lastid = (select MAX(id) from tbltest);
        set i = i +1;
        end while;
        commit;
    end
```

Do you know any good way to benchmark this ? Maybe my procedure needs some improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use MySQL's [**BENCHMARK() function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark)

Here are my posts on how to use it

- `Apr 03, 2012` : [How to use the 'select benchmark' command on a procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15937/how-to-use-the-select-benchmark-command-on-a-procedure/16029#16029)
- `Apr 16, 2013` : [MySQL: CAST + SUBSTR vs. FLOOR + MOD](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/mysql-cast-substr-vs-floor-mod/40170#40170)

BTW if you do configuartion changes, you should restart mysqld immediately after the configuration changes are in place. Then, run your I/O tests.

Comment: Very precise and useful answer :) exactly what i needed :) thanks a lot!